# TFS Process Template XML - Set default System.History value

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I would like to add a custom rule to set a default History when changing the status.

```
      <FIELD name="History" refname="System.History" type="History">
        <HELPTEXT>Discussion thread plus automatic record of changes</HELPTEXT>
    <WHENCHANGED field="System.State">
          <DEFAULT from="value" value="State changed" />
        </WHENCHANGED>
      </FIELD>


getting below error.

**Error importing work item type definition:
TF26062: Rule '<DEFAULT from="value" value="State changed" />' is not supported for the field 'System.History'.**
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the Process xml file, you would like to add a value for the **Discussion** field when the status of this work item changes.

[image]

**Discussion** field of the work item is not supported to use custom rule to set a value when changing status.

You could consider create a new custom field to apply your rule.